# Overflow in std::chrono::duration for remaining time measurement

Tags: c++, c++11, integer-overflow, c++-chrono

I would like to know, how much time is remaining for an event to happen. I'm using boost::chrono or std::chrono for that.

Basically the algorithm is like that:

```
using std::chrono; // Just for this example
auto start = steady_clock::now();
seconds myTotalTime(10);
while(true){
  auto remaining = start + myTotalTime - steady_clock::now();
  seconds remainingSecs = duration_cast<seconds>(remaining);
  if(remainingSecs.count() <= 0) return true;
  else print("Remaining time = " + remainingSecs.count()); // Pseudo-Code!
}
```

Now the following could (theoretically) happen: `start` is near the end of the period of the clock (IMO there is no notion what `0` means, so it could be arbitrary).
Then `start + myTotalTime` could overflow and the subtraction could underflow.

Even simple things like `steady_clock::now() - start` could underflow.

For unsigned types this is not a problem. If they were unsigned, then the standard guarantees that I still get the correct number of "units" for `steady_clock::now() - start` in the case of an overflowed `now()` and the underflowing subtraction: `10 - 250 = 10 + 256 - 255 = 16` for 8bit unsigned math.

But AFAIK over/underflow for signed types is undefined behaviour.

Am I missing anything? Why are the duration and especially time_points defined with signed instead of unsigned types?

Comment: I think you have to decide how long you're going to leave you're computer running before you reach the point where this is a real issue. It's likely `steady_clock::now` returns a measure of how long your computer has been on. Even then, surely you can detect the wrapping and handle it if you believe your program will still be running in a thousand or so years.

Comment: IMO you have to weight the pros-and-cons. It is very unlikely that you'll get an overflow with signed duration unless you let your computer runs for thousand years... And for having designed, implemented and used duration-type like object (e.g. representing various units such as volume, datarate, ...), it is often very handy to have signed type, even if the real units have no negative meaning.

Comment: I think this is a really good question and has incited some good answer. Thanks for asking. I had the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem. You choose the units such that they can't overflow for your needs, surely?

On my system (yes, I know, but) std::chrono::seconds is defined as int64_t, so assuming a sensible epoch is chosen (!= big bang), it won't overflow any time soon.

The others are too, but in nanoseconds that wipes 30 bits off, leaving a good chance of overflow, The remaining 33 bits give /only/ 270 years or so.

time_point internally uses a duration, as it is duration since epoch. In principle, if your epoch is 1970 (Unix), you may want to refer to dates before then, so it has to be signed. If your epoch is 1600 (Windows), you clearly can't use nanoseconds to represent current time points, which is a portability issue.

You can define your own duration using double, of course, where range is exchanged for resolution, and I have done this in the past as a convenient way of printing decimal second timestamps.

Or you could define a larger integer class if you need both range and resolution.

Comment: But portability is exactly the point why I was using `chrono`. Reason for the question is a kind of impossible bug during usage of `boost::chrono` (pre-C++11 code) where a similar code to the above fails. I am using `time_point` and `seconds` as defined in the boost/std standard. So no own `rep`s. But I do want to refer to time_points reasonably close to `now()` of a steady clock. The epoch is an implementation detail that should not bother me. But if e.g. windows decides to set the epoch to 1600 and uses a time_point period of nanoseconds then I'd have a problem due to UB. So what shall I do?

Comment: IMO the only thing would be to use a `time_point<Clock, seconds>` and use `time_point_cast`s. Because we cannot rely on the clock giving seconds or so. BTW: Do you have a reference for your 1600 epoch on windows?

Comment: I just googled windows and epoch. Didn't explore. I started looking for DOS epoch.

Comment: If the underlying library can't support now(), and tell you correctly the delta from epoch to now without wrapping, then it is broken, simple as. The realtime clock has an epoch of "program start", or "processor start" I think, so should be safe to use nanoseconds.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short program you can use to see how much range is left (relative to now) in `steady_clock` for any platform:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace std;
    using days = duration<int, ratio<86400>>;
    using years = duration<double, ratio_multiply<ratio<146097, 400>, days::period>>;
    cout << years{steady_clock::time_point::max() -
                  steady_clock::now()}.count() << " years to go\n";
}
```

This will output the number of years from now that `steady_clock` will overflow.  After running this a few times on a few different platforms, you should get a warm fuzzy feeling that unless your program is going to be running for more than a couple hundred years, you don't need to worry.

On my platform (and this is common), `steady_clock` is measuring the time since boot in units of nanoseconds.

For me this program outputs:

```
292.127 years to go
```

Any platform and any clock that can't represent `now()` without overflow is not likely to be widely adopted.

> Why are the duration and especially time_points defined with signed instead of unsigned types?

- To make `duration` and `time_point` subtraction less error prone.  Yes, if you subtract *unsigned_smaller* - *unsigned_larger* you do get a well-defined result, but that result is not likely to be the answer the programmer is expecting (except in the example of time_point + duration you give).
- So that datetimes prior to 1970 can be represented with `system_clock::time_point`.  Though not specified, it is a de-facto standard that `system_clock` is measuring [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (using various precisions).  And that requires holding negative values to represent times prior to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  I am currently attempting to standardize this existing practice.

Instead, signed integral representation is specified with a sufficient number of bits in an attempt to make overflow a rare problem.  Nanosecond precision is guaranteed to have +/- 292 years of range.  Coarser precisions will have more range than that.  And custom representations are allowed when this default is not sufficient.

Comment: Fantastic example! On a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a high-end Dell laptop, I get `292.277 years to go`